# What is the smallest extension field of $Q$ that contains this radical?

Tags: field-theory

for a radical like $\frac{2+\sqrt[11]{1+\sqrt[5]{3}}}{3}$, what is the smallest extension field of $Q$ that contains it?

I'm not sure how to deal with radicals inside radicals

Comment: What kind of characterization are you looking for? Trivially, we could say that it's $\mathbb Q\left(\frac13\left(2+\sqrt[11]{1+\sqrt[5]3}\right)\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is $\alpha$, then teh smallest extension field is clearly just
$$\Bbb Q[\alpha].$$
By transforming the defining expression,
$$ \bigl((3\alpha-2)^{11}-1\bigr)^5=3,$$
i.e., $\alpha$ is a root of some complicated degree 55 polynomial.
Once we note that $\beta:=3\alpha-2\in\Bbb Q[\alpha]$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb Q[\beta]$, we can look for $\beta$ instead of $\alpha$. As
$$(\beta^{11}-1)^5=3, $$
its polynomial is less horrible:
$$  X^{55} - 5X^{44} + 10X^{33} - 10X^{22} + 5X^{11} - 4$$
No show that is polynomial is irreducible and conclude that
$$ \Bbb Q[\alpha]\cong \Bbb Q[X]/(X^{55} - 5X^{44} + 10X^{33} - 10X^{22} + 5X^{11} - 4).$$